# React DatePicker component

Tags: reactjs

Hi I need help to properly write the code full working for Datepicker: https://reactdatepicker.com/
I have trouble importing the css and after spending too much time I decided to just grab the code. Please help make it work and forgive me as I am new to react. Thanks.

````
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

function DatePicker() {

    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
    const MyContainer = ({ className, children }) => {

        return (
          <div style={{ padding: "16px", background: "#216ba5", color: "#fff" }}>
            <CalendarContainer className={className}>
              <div style={{ background: "#f0f0f0" }}>
                What is your favorite day?
              </div>
              <div style={{ position: "relative" }}>{children}</div>
            </CalendarContainer>
          </div>
        );
      };

      return (
        <DatePicker
          selected={startDate}
          onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
          calendarContainer={MyContainer}
        />
      );
    };

export default DatePicker```
````

Comment: you have issue iwth css?.can you show how it looksn ow

Comment: I can't make this work: import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker-cssmodules.css'; I know there is thread out there for this but I already spent time without result so I decided to grab the code and manully add it  but I am new to react and I don't know what I am lacking in the code above to work.

Comment: let me check once

Comment: thanks. I'm a total beginner so I would appreciate your help make it work. I grabbed it here: https://reactdatepicker.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested it.It loads fine.Here is the code

```
import React from 'react';
import DatePicker,{ CalendarContainer } from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";


function App() {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = React.useState(new Date());
  const MyContainer = ({ className, children }) => {

    return (
      <div >
        <CalendarContainer className={className}>
          <div style={{ background: "#f0f0f0" }}>
            What is your favorite day?
              </div>
          <div style={{ position: "relative" }}>{children}</div>
        </CalendarContainer>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
      calendarContainer={MyContainer}
    />
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting an error: ./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-datepicker' in 'C:\Users\JD\Desktop\date-picker\src'

Comment: you should copy only inside code component not entire think .Since your component name is DatePicker but in my case its App so

Comment: I created a new react app. I figure out I missed to npm install react-datepicker --save let me check again